# selecting the value and then submitting the form using vue.js dosent work

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

My problem is that when I select the input value and then submit the form my `answer` value from the form is empty in `answer.php` - `$_POST['answer']`
here is my html code:

```
<form action="answer.php" ref="send" method="post" class="container">
<h1><?= $question['Question']; ?></h1>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $question['ID']; ?>">
<div class="custom-control custom-radio" v-on:click="demo">
    <input type="radio" id="answer1" name="answer" class="custom-control-input" value="1" v-model="answer">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="answer1"><?= $question['Answer1']; ?></label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="answer2" name="answer" class="custom-control-input" value="2" v-model="answer">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="answer2"><?= $question['Answer2']; ?></label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
    <input type="radio" id="answer3" name="answer" class="custom-control-input" value="3" v-model="answer">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="answer3"><?= $question['Answer3']; ?></label>
</div>
</form>
```

and here is my vue code:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        answer: 0,
    },
    methods: {
        demo() {
            this.answer = 1;
        },
    },
    watch: {
        answer(val) {
            this.$refs.send.submit();
        },
    },
});
```

The form is send like I have never select anything of the form, no `answer`. What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE: I am taking about when someone clicks inside the `div`, but NOT at the text itself. In the 'white' space in the div. That's when my problem happen and I want them to be able to click on the div and select the answer, instead only on the text.**

In the gif below you can see `1` is the value of `answer` and `demo123` is the value of the `id` and when i click on the radio button you can see them changed before the form is send, but you can also see that when the `answer.php` is loaded the value of `id` is `value` (the default one) and there is no `answer` value to be found.
[image]

Comment: i try test your code , it work fine. In my answer.php file, It display $_POST['answer'] . You should check your request in network chrome

Comment: I am getting only the hidden `id` input from the post question i can see in the network tab. I don't see any `answer` value in there, the problem comes from when it is clicked on the `div` instead on the text itself. have you tried that, because this is the functionality I want to be able to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get it work using this code

```
methods: {
    demo() {
        this.$refs.send[1].checked = true;
        this.$refs.send.submit();
    },
},
```

So, when now someone clicked in the `div` the first radio button it's selected and then the form it is send. If someone have a better solution, please let me know! thanks!